# data-bind URL from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding

I am trying to data-bind a URL from my JavaScript to my HTML.  It doesn't work at the moment and I'm not sure why.  I cannot find any online guides covering my exact setup.  I think I might need a .observable somewhere.  Thank you.

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/Helper.js"></script>-->
    <script src="scripts/bpageVM05.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="layout" data-id="main">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="tabstrip">
                <a href="views/home.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: url }" data-icon="reply">Back</a>
                <!--<a href="#" data-icon="reply" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">Back</a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
(function () {
    /*kendo.bind($('body'), mainVM);
    LoadParameters(mainVM);

    // initialize data
    initializeinputs();*/

    // store a reference to the application object that will be created
    // later on so that we can use it if need be
    var app;

    // HTML files: create an object to store the models for each view
    window.APP = 
    {
        models: 
        {
            // Menu -------------------------------------
            home: {
                title: 'Home',
                url: 'views/home.html'
            },
            menu: {
                title: 'Main Menu',
                url: 'views/home.html'
            },
            cards: {
                title: 'Cards',
                url: 'views/menu.html'
            },
            email: {
                title: 'Email Settings',
                url: 'views/menu.html'
            },
            rates: {
                title: 'Card Rates',
                url: 'views/menu.html'
            },
            station: {
                title: 'Station Schedule',
                url: 'views/menu.html'
            },
            parameters: {
                title: 'PLC Parameters',
                url: 'views/menu.html'
            },

            // Reports ----------------------------------
            reports: {
                title: 'Reports',
                url: 'views/home.html'
            },
            reports_activity: {
                title: 'Activity Report',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            },
            reports_payments: {
                title: 'Payments Report',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            },
            reports_cards: {
                title: 'Cards Report',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            },
            reports_printer_1: {
                title: 'Volume Dispensed Log',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            },
            reports_printer_2: {
                title: 'Credit Charges Log',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            },
            reports_printer_3: {
                title: 'Accountable Volume Log',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            },
            reports_printer_4: {
                title: 'Card Numbers Log',
                url: 'views/reports.html'
            }
        }
    }

    // this function is called by Cordova when the application is loaded by the device
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {  

      // hide the splash screen as soon as the app is ready. otherwise
      // Cordova will wait 5 very long seconds to do it for you.
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();

      app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {

        // you can change the default transition (slide, zoom or fade)
        transition: 'slide',

        // comment out the following line to get a UI which matches the look
        // and feel of the operating system
        skin: 'flat',

        // the application needs to know which view to load first
        initial: 'views/home.html'
      });

    }, false);
}());
```

Comment: are you trying to make a back button with javascript?  if so, you can find a solution here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814472/how-to-make-an-html-back-link

Comment: Yes I am.  Will that work for a phone app?  because it freezes my phone emulator in Visual Studio

Comment: are you loading the emulator and then clicking it immediately?  it might be freezing if there wasn't a previous page to go back to.

Comment: no, I am not; it freezes after I have moved a page away from Home.  Which is why I am trying to tell it directly which file to go to

Comment: looks like you're not the only one with this problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691302/test-app-failing-on-back-button-windows-phone-7

Comment: OK, thank you, but do you know how I could tell it directly where to go based on the current screen?